# jQuery: animate function causing long delay when used down a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a list of about 26 `<section>` tags that include some other divs and information. I have it so when you click on a share button, these extra options get shown in that same `<section>` tag. When you click on the share button, this is the jQuery js I use:

```
selectedPost.animate({
  left: -selectedPostWidth
}, 200, function(){
});
sharePost.animate({
  left: 0
}, 200, function(){
  // some stuff
});
```

Now however this is where it gets odd. When you click on one of the buttons inside the share div it plays the reverse animation like so:

```
selectedPost.animate({
  left: 0
}, 200, function(){
});
sharePost.animate({
  left: 9999
}, 200, function(){
  sharePost.hide();
});
```

So in my list of `<section>` tags, the first one works fast and no delay. However, once you start moving down the list, the delay get's greater and greater. Until you have about a 4-5 second delay. This only happens on the *close* function animations, not the open one.

I hope I have explained everything alright, if not I'll add more detail. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I wonder if there's something with how you're binding that's causing the animate to fire a bunch of times.  Can you post your `$(function(){})` as well as your markup?  If you use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (or a similar tool), you could also try adding a `console.log` message inside the `animate()`, and looking at how many times it gets called.

Comment: It would help if you shared all of your code (the click functions & relevant HTML) since it sounds like the events are applied multiple times on a single element.